# How to get the value of a variable of one class in another class without using inheritance and without initialsing init?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Pyhton classes A and B. I want to access the value of x in class B.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def do(self):
        self.x = 1 + 2

class B():
    #get the value of x which is 3, not 0.
```

How do I do this? If I create an instance, **init** is called which re-initializes x to 0, but I want the final value of x which is 3.
Does anyone please have a solution?

Comment: You need to create an instance of `A`, call its `do` method, *then* access its `x` attribute in `B`. But with such an abstract example it's hard to tell what you're really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding dependencies between classes is an important principle of OOP which should not be violated lightly. To the extent that classes need to interchange information, this should happen via public and documented methods.

Python doesn't enforce this, but you should probably be looking for a different way to address whichever problem you hope to solve with this arrangement.

The class `A` doesn't have any `x` which exists in the class itself; the way you have defined the class, `x` is an instance attribute. It is only defined when you have an object which belongs to the class, and each object instance has a value for this variable which is separate from every other instance's. The class itself doesn't have a variable with this name.

Perhaps you are really looking for a class attribute, something like this?

```
class A():
    x = None

    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__.x is None:
            self.__class__.x = 0

    def do(self):
        self.__class__.x = 3

    @classmethod
    def _get_x(cls):
        return cls.x


class B():
    :
        value_of_A_x = A._get_x()
```

The leading underscore in the name of the class method `_get_x` informally suggests that this is a private method.

You'll notice that `x` has three states. It starts out as `None`, then when the first instance of an `A` object is created, it gets set to 0. The first time an instance's `do` method is called, it gets set to 3. There are currently no other ways to change its value, though you are of course free to change this code or add new code in accordance with your requirements.

The above is highly speculative, but should at the very least help you write a better question by explaining what you actually want to achieve. Code which doesn't work at all is not a good way to tell us what you actually want.